# cv2.compare() in OpenCV Python. What does this code snippet mean?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

```
def volume_analysis(self, threshold_image):
    gamma = 0.05
    flag = False
    no_of_pixels = cv2.compare(threshold_image, 0, cv2.CMP_GT).sum() / 255
    if self.prevNoOfPixels is not None:
        if abs(self.prevNoOfPixels - no_of_pixels) / self.prevNoOfPixels > gamma:
            flag = True
    self.prevNoOfPixels = no_of_pixels
    return flag
```

I am guessing that `cv2.compare(threshold_image, 0, cv2.CMP_GT).sum()` is substracting an empty or 0 matrix from threshold image and storing it in a matrix that has something to do with `cv2.CMP_GT` `.sum()` is probably finding the number of pixels from that matrix. Am I right?

However, I couldn't find any official python documentation on the function `cv2.compare()` or on `cv2.CMP_GT` or on `.sum()` {used in such a way}. I did see that there are some articles on these keywords being used in C++. I will be grateful if someone can explain what these mean or share some documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no subtraction taking place only **comparison**

`cv2.compare` performs an element-wise comparison. In simple words, given the following instance:

```
cv2.compare(a, b, cv2.CMP_GT)
```

every element in array A is compared with every element in array B. The flag `cv2.CMP_GT` is used to check whether the element in A is greater than of B in each comparison. It returns another array containing `0` and `255`; where

- `0` -> element in `A` is **not** greater than that in `B`
- `255` -> element in `A` **is** greater than that in `B`

OpenCV limits the range between `0-255` internally.

In the following case:

```
cv2.compare(A, B, cv2.CMP_GT).sum()
```

it returns a scalar, the sum of all positions in array `A` where it is greater than that of array `B`

**Illustration:**

Consider an array:

```
A
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [-1, -2, -3],
       [ 4,  0,  0]])
```

compared with `0`

```
cv2.compare(a, 0, cv2.CMP_GT)
```

returns `255` where elements in `A` are greater than `0`:

```
array([[255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

The following would return number of positions where `A` is greater than `0`:

```
cv2.compare(a, 0, cv2.CMP_GT).sum()/255

>>> 4.0
```

**Other options:**

Here are the list of flags that can be used:

- `CMP_EQ`: equal to
- `CMP_GE`: greater than or equal to
- `CMP_GT`: greater than
- `CMP_LE`: lesser than
- `CMP_LT`: lesser than or equal to
- `CMP_NE`: not equal to

[Link to various flags used](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0cc47ff833d40b58ecbe1d609a53d784)

Comment: I have two questions. 
1. When you talk about comparing A(an image) with 0, does it mean that a greyscale image(1 matrix) is being compared with a 0 matrix?(This is probably the case because it is returning the number of pixels in the image and not number of pixels*3) Why is it not comparing 3 matrices(RGB) with 3 zero matrices?
2. So this function is trying to switch a flag based on the number of non white pixels in an image? There's a good chance that the function will return the total number of pixels each time right?
Moreover thank you for the answer. You explained it very well.

Comment: @A7sus4 In the given example, `A` is a single channel matrix (similar to grayscale). The same can be done if `A` is an RGB with 3 channels. The result would also be a 3-channel matrix with value `255` in positions where the pixel is greater than 0. For the second question, the value `255` is placed if the comparison is satisfied. Adding all the values and dividing by 255 gives the number of pixels.